# Android restart IntentService when application runs from another

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I use `IntentService` to perform API requests to server. When application launches, `IntentService` always starts, performs synchronization and sends broadcast to my `BroadcastReceiver`. Also I can send photos from another applications. When I do that, I want restart my IntentService even if it hasn't done its work. I've tried to call

```
stopService(new Intent(this, SyncApiService.class));
startService(new Intent(this, SyncApiService.class));
```

But, as I've understood, this way doesn't work because `onReceive` method calls twice. Is there any way to restart IntentService?

I call this method in `onCreate` of my `Activity`:

```
private void requestForMemmoryPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_STORAGE);
    } else {
        SyncApiService.startActionFullSync(this, AuthPreferences.getAuthToken(this), AuthPreferences.getDeviceToken(this), false);
    }
}
```

I want restart Service in `onNewIntent` method:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    readDataFromIntentFilter(intent);
    SyncApiService.stop(this);
    requestForAccessNetworkStatePermission();
}
```

Method `requestForAccessNetworkStatePermission` calls `requestForMemoryPermission` inside. And there's my service:

```
public class SyncApiService extends IntentService {

    public SyncApiServive() {
        super("SyncApiService");
    }

    public static void stop(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncApiService.class);
        context.stopService(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Starting of full synchronization process
     * @param context
     * @param authToken
     * @param deviceId
     * @param neddImport
    */
    public static void startActionFullSync(Context context, String authToken, String deviceId, boolean neddImport) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SyncApiService.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_FULL_SYNC);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_AUTH_TOKEN, authToken);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ID, deviceId);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NEED_IMPORT, neddImport);
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case ACTION_FULL_SYNC:
                    String authToken = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_AUTH_TOKEN);
                    String deviceId = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ID);
                    boolean needImport = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_NEED_IMPORT, false);
                    handleActionFullSync(authToken, deviceId, needImport, action);
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(API_TAG, "!!!onDestroy!!!");
        NotificationHelper.cancel(getApplicationContext(), NotificationHelper.SYNC_NOTIFICATION);
    }

    private void handleActionFullSync(String authToken, String deviceId, boolean needImport, String action) {
        // TODO: full sync process
        //NotificationHelper.showSyncNotification(getApplicationContext(),  R.string.sync_notification, R.string.cloud_sync, R.string.cloud_sync);
        //startCloudSync(authToken, deviceId);
        NotificationHelper.showSyncNotification(getApplicationContext(), R.string.sync_notification, R.string.photo_sync, R.string.photo_sync);
        startPhotoSync(authToken, deviceId, needImport);
    }

    private void startPhotoSync(String authToken, String deviceId, boolean needImport) {
        getOldPhotoSync(authToken, deviceId);
        if (needImport) uploadNewPhotoSync(authToken, deviceId);
        else {
            Log.i(API_TAG, "!!!NO IMPORT!!!");
            NotificationHelper.cancel(getApplicationContext(), NotificationHelper.SYNC_NOTIFICATION);
            Intent intent = new Intent(AppActivity.SYNC_FILTER);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NEED_IMPORT, needImport);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

So I want stop this actions when `onNewIntent` calls

Comment: `IntentService` doesn't work that way. When you call `startService()` on an `IntentService`, the service is started (if it isn't already running) and `onHandleIntent()` is called. When `onHandleIntent()` completes, if there is another `Intent` to be processed, `onHandleIntent()` will be called again. If there are no more `Intent`s to be processed, the service stops itself.

There shouldn't be any reason why you would need to stop and restart the `Service`. If you think there is a reason for that, please post your code and we can look at it again.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you mean when you say that `onReceive()` is called twice. You should post the relevant code so that we can look at it.